# IoT Edge Device Keeping Removed Modules - Sending in Module Twin Lists *BUG*

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I have created an IoT Hub Edge device.    In the beginning, the default $edgeAgent and $edgeHub modules went in.  That's fine.    Then I added a "barkModule" (note the lower-case B at the start) -- just a test module to play with D2C event messages and DirectMethod calls to the module.

Later on, I removed that module and added a new one, this time with BarkModule (capital B).     Been rocking this way for about a week.

I did this bit of code to get a list of a devices module twins (_deviceTwins is the twins of all the devices on the hub, this is basically just getting all the modules for the device) :

```
    foreach (var _device in _deviceTwins) {
        var moduleList = await registryManager.GetModulesOnDeviceAsync(_device.DeviceId);
        DeviceList.Add(new DeviceAndModules { DeviceTwin = _device, Modules = moduleList.ToList() });
    };
```

In its module twin list -- I'm getting an entry for *both* BarkModule and barkModule.     Even though my device just has $edgeAgent, $edgeHub and BarkModule modules.

I even went digging in $edgeAgent's module twin, and there's a *ton* of meta-data event history stuff (seriously, this is absurdly large) -- but there's **NO** reference to the lowercase-b "barkModule" anywhere.

How is it maintaining this information?  Why is this showing up still?   Is there a way I can remove this?

This shows the modules:
[image: shows four modules]

This shows there's only three:
[image: Only three on the device]

Comment: Added it as a bug to Edge's github issues page:
https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/570